# ¿Es incorrecto decir que algo se remonta años atrás?

Tags: gramática, sintaxis, tiempo, redundancia

"Remontarse", con la idea de algo en el pasado, se puede relacionar con siguientes entradas del DLE:

> [**remontar**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Vuxkcmf)
>
> 15. *prnl*. Retroceder hasta una época pasada. *Este historiador se ha remontado hasta la época prehistórica*.
> 16. *prnl*. Pertenecer a una época muy lejana. *Esta iglesia se remonta al siglo XII.*

Eso me da la idea de que implícitamente al usar el verbo "remontar" ya se dice que es en el pasado. Pero me he encontrado estos ejemplos:

- ["El origen de esta historia se remonta a miles de años atrás](https://www.pinterest.co.uk/pin/511862313898248650/) [...] la historia ha ido aumentando su tamaño, deformándose, adoptando nuevos significados y volviéndose contradictoria con el paso de los siglos.
- [El último triunfo cartagenero en Barcelona se remonta a doce años atrás](https://www.sportcartagena.es/articulo/futbol-sala/ultimo-triunfo-cartagenero-barcelona-remonta-doce-anos-atras/20190223103057076448.html).
- [Una trayectoria que se remonta 30 años atrás](https://www.diariovasco.com/v/20120630/alto-deba/trayectoria-remonta-anos-atras-20120630.html).
- [La historia sobre el origen del taco se remonta a por lo menos 200 años atrás](https://www.univision.com/noticias/amexica/la-historia-sobre-el-origen-del-taco-se-remonta-a-por-lo-menos-200-anos-atras).

¿Es redundante el uso que se le da en las anteriores frases o es correcto?

Comment: No creo que sea redundante, sobre todo por que el principal uso de remontar se refiere a "subir", asi que hay que agregar el "atras" para hacer incapie de que hablamos de algo historico. y creo presisamente que ese es el significado de REMONTAR, de "subirnos(-montar) otra vez(-re) a una era en el pasado para ponernos en contexto", ejemplo: "vamos a montarnos a 5 años en el futuro" vs "vamos a remontarnos a 5 años en el pasado"

Answer (score 2):

No veo que sea redundante porque la definición de remontar no determina un marco de tiempo exacto.

Si remontar es «Retroceder hasta una época pasada» dicha época puede ser «años atrás», «décadas atrás», «siglos atrás», «eones atrás», etc.

Por lo anterior especificar que son solamente años no solo no me parece redundante sino necesario.

Answer (score 2):

No creo que ese "atrás "sea redundante necesariamente en todos los casos, si no una manera de aclarar "desde donde" se remonta o desambiguar posibles acepciones de "remontar". Además, "redundante" no quiere decir por necesidad "incorrecto".

Por ejemplo "Se remonta 200 años atrás (desde nuestros días)" vs. "Se remonta 200 años antes de la llegada de Colón".

Decir "Se remonta (a) 200 años" (sin el "atrás") es posible.

> Birmania tiene una historia de dictadura militar que se remonta a unos cincuenta años, y condenamos el hecho de que sus ciudadanos no hayan [...]
>
> El origen de la insatisfacción indígena se remonta a hace unos años.
>
> Según los arqueólogos, su historia se remonta a unos 21.000 años.
>
> La Sra. MARTÍNEZ (Uruguay) dice que la disposición en cuestión del Código Civil se remonta a unos 150 años.
>
> Ejemplos de [Liguee](https://www.linguee.com/spanish-english/translation/se+remonta+a+unos+cuantos+a%C3%B1os.html)

El "atrás" puede parecer redundante, ya que uno no se remonta "al futuro", pero no es necesariamente un error. Compara con

> Sube arriba de ese árbol y dime qué ves (uno no "sube abajo")
>
> Baja aquí abajo y hablemos ("abajo" es de nuevo redundante, pero no necesariamente un error).

Repito que "redundante" no quiere decir por necesidad "incorrecto".

Es posible que ese "atrás" pueda usarse para clarificar entre las distintas acepciones de "remontar". Cierto que nadie pensaría al decir

> El último triunfo se remonta 200 años

que ese "remontar" implica "subir" o "ascender", pero el uso de "atrás" completa el sentido de referencia temporal.

Con otros verbos, como "hacer" sí puede haber un mal uso de "atrás". Consulta "[Hace un mes o un mes atrás, pero no hace un mes atrás](https://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/hace-un-mes-o-un-mes-atras-pero-no-hace-un-mes-atras-1116/)"

> La expresión *hace un mes atrás*, en lugar de *hace un mes* o *un mes atrás*, es impropia en español.